# How to share file main.js in reactjs multiple entry points app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I created an reactjs app with multiple entry points (23 entry points). The total size of all static files is 250Mb, the file main.js is about 1-2Mb and main.js.map is about 5-10Mb.

I noticed that the file main.js seems to contain common libraries: React, preserve, perfect-scrollbar, ReactJs, ....

How to reduce the size of static files? How to share the common libraries?

[image]

Comment: I might convert my app to spa to reduce the size of javascript and css